# Бот VK API. Не реагирует на сообщения

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, php7

Хочу перейти на последнюю версию VK API (5.103), но бот не реагирует на сообщения, узнал, что в этой версии надо добавлять объект client_info, но как это сделать? Буду очень признателен, если поможете. Желательно ориентироваться на мой код:

```php
<?php

    //ключ группы, который мы должны вернуть серверу VK API
    $group_token = 'beb...';

    //функция отправки сообщений
    function vk_msg_send($randomID, $peer_id, $text_msg){
        $randomID = rand().time();

        //запрашиваем и отправляем параметры серверу
        $request_params_msg = array(
            'message' => $text_msg,
            'random_id' => $randomID,
            'peer_id' => $peer_id,
            'access_token' => "access_group_token",
            'v' => '5.103'
        );
        $get_params_msg = http_build_query($request_params_msg);
        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params_msg);
    }

    /*создаём переменную, в которой будем получать данные (запрос) от пользователя (через VK API) в виде JSON-файла и декодировать (переводить) их в обычный php  
     *в дальнейшем трансформируем (производим какие-то действия с этими данными), переводим обратно в JSON-формат и отправляем их VK API, а он уже формирует окончательный ответ для пользователя
     */
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    //ловим тип данных (события), которые нам отправляет сервер VK API
    switch ($data->type) {

        //отправляем ответ VK API на запрос 'confirmation' в виде нашего ключа из переменной "group_token" для установки связи с сервером
        case 'confirmation':
            echo $group_token;
        break;

        /*подключаемся к событию "message_new"
         *ловим и проверяем сообщения
         */
        case 'message_new':
            $message_text = $data -> object -> text;
            $chat_id = $data -> object -> peer_id;
            $id_random = $data -> object -> random_id;

            // если переменная "message_text" (сообщение пользователя) будет равна указанному нами строковому значению, тогда мы будем отправлять пользователю строковый ответ через переменную "chat_id"
            if ($message_text == "привет" || $message_text == "Привет"){
                vk_msg_send($id_random, $chat_id, "Привет");
            }
            else if ($message_text == "пока" || $message_text == "Пока"){
                vk_msg_send($id_random, $chat_id, "Пока");
            }
            else {
                vk_msg_send($id_random, $chat_id, "Ты что-то сказал?");
            }

            //отвечаем этим сообщением на все запросы сервера VK API, чтобы подтвердить, что всё сработало верно и всё ОК
            echo 'ok';
        break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: добавить в массив $request_params_msg?
ключ -> значение?)

Comment: Ахах, если бы всё было так просто, я бы не задавал этот вопрос, хотя для большинства он может показаться простым, но не настолько же) Кстати, насчёт значения, хотел бы ещё узнать, как правильно рандомить этот уникальный идентификатор для бесед. Может я просто не правильно рандомлю значение? В общем, буду рад, если поможете)) Обновил код, добавил вариант, который нашёл в инете, но увы, он не робит, так что прошу, помогите ламеру

Comment: Не надо давать ссылку на код. Вставьте текстом в вопрос.

Comment: @Amadeus246, так у вас нормальная практика `mt_rand(20, 99999999)`. В чем проблема? Можете попробовать так: `'random_id' => rand().time()`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, как я понимаю у этого сайта есть СТО для вставки кода, я ещё не успел с ним ознакомиться, а pastebin - отличный, проверенный сервис для демонстрации, извиняюсь за неудобства

Comment: @Let'ssayPie я так понимаю это увеличивающееся значение? Сейчас попробую

Comment: Оказывается на 103 версии нужно добавлять ещё объект client_info, только вот как?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо ошибка где-то в функции если ты правильно вставил токен и т. д. Попробуй вот такую функцию

```
$rand = rand(0000000000, 9999999999).time("Ymd");

Функция:
function vk_send($method, $request) {

    $get_params = http_build_query($request);
    json_decode(file_get_contents(VK_API_ENDPOINT.$method.$get_params.'&access_token='.VK_API_TOKEN.'&v='.VK_API_VERSION));
    echo('ok');

}
```

при этом запрос такой:

```
$userId = $data->object->peer_id;

            $request_params = array(

                'random_id' => $rand,
                'user_id' => $userId,
                'message' => "Привет"

            );

            //Отправление сообщения
            vk_send('messages.send?', $request_params);
```

У меня работает.

Comment: С рандомом уже разобрался, но в 103 версии требуют ещё объект client_info, как его добавить?

Comment: Начиная с версии API 5.103 информация о доступных функциях будет приходить вместе с событием message_new в Callback API и Bots Long Poll API. Она будет находиться в объекте client_info:

Comment: Ничего добавлять не нужно это доп. информация в событии которая будет приходить

Comment: У меня всё работает на 5.102, но когда перехожу на 103, то перестаёт. На этом сайте **https://kotoff.net/article/40-sozdanie-bota-vk-na-inline-knopkah-i-obnovlenie-na-versiju-api-5103-podrobnaja-instrukcija-i-primery.html** пишут, цитирую: "Если Вы использовали версию ниже 5.103, то после смены, на версию 5.103 и выше, ваш бот перестанет отвечать на сообщения в 100% случаях, все потому, что был добавлен новый объект client_info", но их методы исправления у меня не работают видимо из-за того, что они используют библиотеку